# Can't attach the adapter to the RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Why can't I attach the adapter to `RecyclerView`? Just constantly getting `W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

**Fragment class**

```
class Latest : Fragment() {

private var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
private var mAdapter: CurrencyAdapter? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val asd = HashMap<String, Double>()
    asd.put("asd", 1.2)
    asd.put("as2d", 3.2)

    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: " + asd.keys + " " + asd.values)

    mRecyclerView = view?.findViewById(R.id.latest_rv)
    mRecyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    mAdapter = CurrencyAdapter(asd)
    mRecyclerView?.adapter = mAdapter

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latest, container, false)
     }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
    class CurrencyAdapter(private val data: HashMap<String, Double>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CurrencyAdapter.ViewHolder>(){


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.currency_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.currencyOrigin.text = data.keys.toTypedArray()[position]
        holder.currencyValue.text = data.values.toTypedArray()[position].toString()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 1
    }

    class ViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView) {
        val currencyOrigin: TextView = ItemView.findViewById(R.id.currency_origin)
        val currencyValue: TextView = ItemView.findViewById(R.id.currency_value)
    }
}
```

Comment: You try to access RecyclerView before layout is inflated, so everything you do has no effect whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

You Should not put your codes in onCreateView, Put them inside onViewCreated method like this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val asd = HashMap<String, Double>()
        asd.put("asd", 1.2)
        asd.put("as2d", 3.2)

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: " + asd.keys + " " + asd.values)

        mRecyclerView = view?.findViewById(R.id.latest_rv)
        mRecyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
        mAdapter = CurrencyAdapter(asd)
        mRecyclerView?.adapter = mAdapter
    }
```

Because the view is created after onCreateView method. so inside the onCreateView you can't manipulate items of view. For more info, you can refer to:
[Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle)

Comment: Answer is correct, but it would be great if you provided explanation why it should be done this way